# Dataweave - how to group by and sum details form array of elements

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

hope you are well, how can I generate dynamic arrays by state? That is, maybe the payload in this case has two types of state (hold, fail) but in another case maybe it has different I don't know and the output payload needs to check the state in the input group by state, remove the fields you don't need and create a total field per state and add those that belong to it...

Input:

```
[
 {
   "numorder": "470",
   "message": "Order number 470 already registered.",
   "status": "hold",
   "description":"",
   "createAt":""
 },
 {
   "numorder": "471",
   "message": "Order number 471 already registered.",
   "status": "failure",
   "description":"",
   "createAt":""
 },{
   "numorder": "472",
   "message": "Order number 472 already registered.",
   "status": "failure",
   "description":"",
   "createAt":""
 }
]
```

Output:

```
{
  "totalHold":1,
  "totalFailure":2,
  "items":[
     { 
        "hold":[
           {
              "numorder":"470",
              "message":"Order number 470 already registered."
           }
        ],
        "failure":[
           {
              "numorder":"471",
              "message":"Order number 471 already registered."
           },
           {
              "numorder":"472",
              "message":"Order number 472 already registered."
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
```

}

**NOTE: the state has to be dynamic because I don't know if the input is failure, hold, success, etc.**

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic? No se hable más...

First of all, you need to group by status and then count all the elements for every group found, this will be the base for the complete solution

```js
var results = 
        payload groupBy ((item, index) -> item.status)
        pluck ((value, key, index) -> 
            (key as String): sizeOf(value)
        )
```

This will give you the next result:

```json
[
  {
    "hold": 2
  },
  {
    "failure": 2
  },
  {
    "success": 1
  }
]
```

Then, you need to convert the array of objects of status to a single object where every element is the status found:

```js
{(
    results map ((item, index) -> 
        item mapObject ((total, status, index) -> 
            (status): total
        )
    ) 
)}
```

This will give you next result:

```json
{
  "hold": 2,
  "failure": 2,
  "success": 1
}
```

Next, based on the first result array, iterate over every status and filter the payload, then print only the numorder and message attribute

```js
{ 
  "items":
    results map ((item, index) -> 
        item mapObject ((total, status, index) -> 
            (status as String): 
                (payload filter ((itemPayload, indexPayload) -> 
                    itemPayload.status == (status as String))
                        map ((item, index) -> { 
                            "numorder": item.numorder,
                            "message": item.message
                        })
                )
            )
        )
}
```

In order to test the results, I added an extra 2 elements with a different status and with and different order (not together)

```json
[
 {
   "numorder": "470",
   "message": "Order number 470 already registered.",
   "status": "hold",
   "description":"",
   "createAt":""
 },
 {
   "numorder": "471",
   "message": "Order number 471 already registered.",
   "status": "failure",
   "description":"",
   "createAt":""
 },
 {
   "numorder": "472",
   "message": "Order number 472 already registered.",
   "status": "failure",
   "description":"",
   "createAt":""
 },
 {
   "numorder": "473",
   "message": "Order number 473 already registered.",
   "status": "success",
   "description":"",
   "createAt":""
 },
  {
   "numorder": "474",
   "message": "Order number 474 already registered.",
   "status": "hold",
   "description":"",
   "createAt":""
 } 
]
```

The final result is:

```json
{
  "hold": 2,
  "failure": 2,
  "success": 1,
  "items": [
    {
      "hold": [
        {
          "numorder": "470",
          "message": "Order number 470 already registered."
        },
        {
          "numorder": "474",
          "message": "Order number 474 already registered."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "failure": [
        {
          "numorder": "471",
          "message": "Order number 471 already registered."
        },
        {
          "numorder": "472",
          "message": "Order number 472 already registered."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "success": [
        {
          "numorder": "473",
          "message": "Order number 473 already registered."
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The complete code:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var results = 
        payload groupBy ((item, index) -> item.status)
        pluck ((value, key, index) -> 
            (key as String): sizeOf(value)
        )
---
{(
    results map ((item, index) -> 
        item mapObject ((total, status, index) -> 
            (status): total
        )
    ) 
)}
++
{ 
  "items":
    results map ((item, index) -> 
        item mapObject ((total, status, index) -> 
            (status as String): 
                (payload filter ((itemPayload, indexPayload) -> 
                    itemPayload.status == (status as String))
                        map ((item, index) -> { 
                            "numorder": item.numorder,
                            "message": item.message
                        })
                )
            )
        )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the status calculation dynamic whereby it could be any value. This capitalizes hold and failure in the output.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Strings
var outputKeys = payload groupBy ((item, index) -> item.status ) mapObject {
    ($$) :  sizeOf($)
}
---
(payload groupBy $.status mapObject {
    ("total" ++ capitalize(((outputKeys pluck $$)[($$$)]))) : outputKeys[($$)]

})
++
(items: [payload groupBy $.status mapObject ((value, key, index) -> {
        (  ((outputKeys pluck $$)[(index)]) : value map (
             $ - 'status' - 'description' - 'createAt'
        ))
}
)])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `items` in your expected output is essentially the output of the [`groupBy`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-groupby) function with just a few fields. So you can use map after groupBy to get your required item list.

For the total**Status** part, I created a helper function `capitalizeFirst` to make it easy for capitalizing the first letter of the status. Putting it together it will look like this

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json

//This function takes a string and capitalizes the first letter of it. it will help to in the fields of totals i.e. "hold" to "totalHold"
fun capitalizeFirst(string: String) = upper(string[0]) ++ (string[1 to -1] default '')
//Simply a helper function to make code more readable. This is to basically keep the required fields only from paylaod.
fun getItemFields(fullItemArray) = fullItemArray map {
    numorder: $.numorder,
    message: $.message,
}

var groupedData = payload groupBy $.status
var statusTotals = groupedData mapObject ('total' ++ capitalizeFirst($$)): sizeOf($)
---
{
    (statusTotals),
    items: [ groupedData mapObject ($$): getItemFields($) ]
}
```

Comment: You could use the capitalize function instead.

Comment: I thought about it too, but it changes the string of there are underscores. But yes, if that is not a problem for OP, `dw::core::Strings::capitalize` is better alternative to the `capitalizeFirst` function above

Answer (score -1):

Updated to make it dynamic:

```
%dw 2.0
import capitalize from dw::core::Strings
output application/json  
---
do {
  var grpSts = payload groupBy $.status
  var keys = grpSts pluck $$
  var values = grpSts pluck $
  ---
  ((
      (keys map 
     ("total" ++ capitalize($)) : sizeOf(grpSts[$]
     )
  )) reduce ((item, acc = {}) ->  acc ++ item)) ++ (
    items: grpSts pluck 
      ($$): ($ map ($ - 'status' - 'description' - 'createAt'))

  )
}
```

Comment: The status are dynamic and can be anything, so you can not use `totalHold` or `grpSts.hold`.